# Using triangle similarity to find a side length

Tags: geometry

I have been pretty much staring at this for an hour. It seems so simple, but I just can't figure it out.. How do I find the length of TS?

By the way, it is hard to see, but < TUA is indeed a right angle.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two sets of similar triangles, $\triangle OBN \sim \triangle OTS, \triangle OBG \sim \triangle OTE  $

The simplest way I see is

$$\frac{5.8}{4.35} = \frac{OA+.45}{OA}$$

the ratio of side lengths is the same as ratio of heights for similar triangles.

Then apply the Pythagorean theorem using the value of $OA$ solved above

$$(OA+.45)^2 + (\frac{TS}{2})^2 = 2^2$$

Comment: Could you explain what you did there? I am not quite skilled enough in the math ways yet ;) Thanks for responding!

Comment: @user3402545 I've added detail